# Few $scope variable values are undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

I have a add route form. I am able to get distance, description `$scope` values from view to controller, but for one field terminal stop which is auto generated value before submitting form is undefined in the $scope value. 
Can you any one suggest me what's wrong , it is any call back/ loading issue.

```
  <form class="well form-horizontal" id="addRouteForm" ng-submit="r.addRoute()">
    <fieldset>
        <!-- Route Description-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Description</label>
            <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                    <textarea name="description" ng-model="route.description" placeholder="Enter route description" class="form-control" type="text" required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Route distance-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Route Distance</label>
            <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span>
                    <input name="distance" ng-model="route.distance" placeholder="12.56 km" class="form-control" type="number" step="00.01" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Route distance-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Terminal stop</label>
            <div class="inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span>
                    <input name="terminalstop" ng-model="route.routeTerminalStop" id="terminalstop" value={{route.routeTerminalStop}} placeholder="Terminal stop" class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="submit" id="submitRoute" value="addRoute" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-placement="top" ng-disabled="r.isNotLoaded" ng-show="saveRoute">Save <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>
    </button>
```

ctrl.js:

```
vm.addRoute = function () {

    vm.isNotLoaded = true;            
    vm.responseMessage = "";

    var route = $scope.route;
    var y = document.getElementById("terminalstop").value; 
    var x = $scope.routeTerminalStop;
```

through var y, I am able to get but var x is undefined. Either Route has terminal stop which is undefined.

Comment: Your function doesn't accept any parameters however you supply parameters to your function in your template. Other than that, the part of the controller that defines your `route` property would be nice to know.

Comment: typo. I am not providing params. Using Form submit and getting value via scope.

Comment: Then show us where is data defined. Because if data is not defined then x will obviously be undefined. You might want to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: forget about data. its all about $scope cannot get terminal stop value. Please consider this var route = $scope.route;

Comment: var x = `$scope.route.routeTerminalStop;` will make the work.

Comment: We do not know your code. We can't see how `$scope.route` gets filled in the first place. That means for all we know `$scope.route` could already be `undefined` or `null` the moment your function gets called.

Comment: Any how , my problem is resolved. $scope variable should be declared globally for that controller. It got resolved.Thank you.

Comment: i cannot not understand why you already have ng-model="route.routeTerminalStop" but still have value={{route.routeTerminalStop}}...

Comment: I was using value to assign from  another module in some other case. Ng-model will get data to controller. value=={{}} will put value from controller.